# Apollo Server 2 support Content-Type application/graphql?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

Does Apollo Server 2 support the Content-Type 'application/graphql'?

Looked but haven't found a concrete answer since Apollo Server 2 was released.

Comment: looking at their docs, like https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server, did you file an issue over on https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server to ask for that information to be added to the docs?

Comment: No - that's a good idea - will do now. There isn't anything definitive in the docs as far as I could see.